# How do I force extraction to fail if the destination directory doesn't exist?

Tags: perl, extract, archive

I’m using Perl 5.16.3 with [`Archive::Extract`](http://metacpan.org/module/Archive::Extract)

I am extracting a zip file, but I would like Perl to fail (die) if the destination directory doesn’t exist. Currently the below code does not fail, but creates the directory before extraction takes place

```
use Archive::Extract;
...

my $ae = Archive::Extract->new( archive => $downloadedFile, type => 'zip' );
my $ok = $ae->extract( to => $deployDir ) or die $ae->error;
```

How can I force things to die if the destination directory doesn’t exist?

Comment: Could use something like: `die "$deployDir does not exist" unless -d $deployDir`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing in the module that allows you to disable the automatic creation of the directory, so you just check it in a separate statement prior to the `extract` call

```
-d $deployDir or die {Deployment directory "$deployDir" doesn't exist};
```

Or you could use [`autodie`](http://metacpan.org/module/autodie) and try to open it as a directory. That way the system will generate a `die` message for you. Like this

```
{
    use autodie;
    opendir my ($dh), $deployDir;
}
```

This requires Perl v5.10.1 or later. The braces `{ ... }` around the code are required. They limit the scope of `autodie` and automatically close the directory handle again immediately